# Prevent using oEmbed for a specific domain

Tags: embed, oembed

We have a custom block that lets people embed content from https://somedomain.com.

The problem is that somedomain.com supports oEmbed poorly, and we’d rather use our own block.

Currently, if someone pastes a URL from somedomain.com into the block editor, it is automatically parsed into an Embed block. We’d like to stop that from happening, and encourage them to use our custom block instead.

How can I tell WordPress to NOT use the available oEmbed for somedomain.com? (while still using oEmbed for every other domain).  Note that somedomain.com is not one of the listed providers in wordpress core, so I can't simply remove the provider. It is just a random site that supports oEmbed.